# node.js - if statement not working as expected

Tags: json, node.js, reduce

This piece of node.js code is run against a Spark History Server API.

What its supposed to do is find any jobs where the name matches the value passed in by uuid and return the id for only that job.

What the below code actually does is if the uuid is found in any job name, the id for every job is returned.

I think this has something to do with the way I'm parsing the JSON but I'm not entirely sure.

How do I change this so it works as I would like it to?

```
var arrFound = Object.keys(json).filter(function(key) {
    console.log("gel json[key].name" + json[key].name);
    return json[key].name;
}).reduce(function(obj, key){
    if (json[key].name.indexOf(uuid)) {
        obj = json[key].id;
    return obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` is the wrong method for that. Use `find` or `filter`. You can even do that in the `filter` callback that you already have. And then you can chain a `map` to that to get the `id` property values for each matched key:

```
var arrFound = Object.keys(json).filter(function(key) {
    console.log("gel json[key].name " + json[key].name);
    return json[key].name && json[key].name.includes(uuid);
}).map(function(key) {
    return json[key].id;
});

console.log (arrFound); // array of matched id values
```

Note also that your use of `indexOf` is wrong. You need to compare that value with -1 (not found). But nowadays you can use `includes` which returns a boolean.

Note that with `Object.values` you list the objects instead of the keys, which is more interesting in your case:

```
var arrFound = Object.values(json).filter(function(obj) {
    console.log("gel obj.name " + obj.name);
    return obj.name && obj.name.includes(uuid);
}).map(function(obj) {
    return obj.id;
});

console.log (arrFound); // array of matched id values
```

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer provides working code, I feel it's worth pointing out that `reduce` is a good way to solve this problem, and to me makes more sense than chaining `filter` and `map`:

```js
const jobs = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'job: 2a2912c5-9ec8-4ead-9a8f-724ab44fc9c7'
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'job: 30ea8ab2-ae3f-4427-8e44-5090d064d58d'
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'job: 5f8abe54-8417-4b3c-90f1-a7f4aad67cfb'
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'job: 30ea8ab2-ae3f-4427-8e44-5090d064d58d'
  }
}

const matchUUID = uuid =>
  (acc, job) => job.name.includes(uuid) ? [ ...acc, job.id ] : acc

const target = '30ea8ab2-ae3f-4427-8e44-5090d064d58d'
const matchTarget = matchUUID(target)

// [ 2, 4 ]
console.log(Object.values(jobs).reduce(matchTarget, []))
```

`reduce` is appropriate for these kinds of problems: taking a larger, more complex or complete value, and *reducing* it to the data you require. On large datasets, it could also be more efficient since you only need to traverse the collection once.

If you're Node version-constrained or don't want to use array spread, here's a slightly more 'traditional' version:

```js
var result = Object.keys(jobs).reduce(
  function (acc, key) {
    if (jobs[key].name.includes(uuid)) {
      acc.push(jobs[key].id)
    }
    return acc
  },
  []
)
```

Note use of `Object.keys`, since `Object.values` is ES2017 and may not always be available. `String.prototype.includes` is ES2015, but you could always use  `indexOf` if necessary.